# Can't use SharedPreferences properly

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make an app which will save locations of some memorable places. I am using `SharedPreferences` to save the locations but it is not being saved. Whenever the user long clicks on the
map the location is saved. App works all fine but when it is reopened it loses the locations.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    static   ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    static   ArrayList<LatLng> positions = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    static int count =0;
    static int flag =0;
    static int pos;
    String countString;

    public void add(View view) {
        flag=0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(" com.example.memorableplaces",MODE_PRIVATE);
        ArrayList<String> latitudes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> longitudes = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            countString = sharedPreferences.getString("count","0");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        count = Integer.parseInt(countString);

        Log.i("count",countString);
        addresses.clear();
        positions.clear();
        latitudes.clear();
        longitudes.clear();

        try {
            addresses = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("addresses", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));
            latitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("lats", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));
            longitudes = (ArrayList<String>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString("lons", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<>())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("size",Integer.toString(addresses.size()));
        i f(addresses.size() > 0) {
            Log.i("ok","ok");
            for (int i = 0; i < latitudes.size(); i++) {
                positions.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitudes.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(longitudes.get(i))));
            }
        }

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addresses);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                flag=1;
                pos = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("check","see");
            }
         });
    }
}
```

MapsActivity :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    Marker previous,current;
    int flag;
    int pos;
    String countString;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

       mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);


        if(MainActivity.flag==0) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.i("Location", location.toString());
                    previous.remove();
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    current = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));

                    previous = current;


                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                previous = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("You are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
            LatLng position = MainActivity.positions.get(MainActivity.pos);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(MainActivity.addresses.get(MainActivity.pos)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
        }





    }





    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        String address = "";

        try {

            List<Address> listAdddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);

            if (listAdddresses != null && listAdddresses.size() > 0) {
                if (listAdddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null) {
                    if (listAdddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() != null) {
                        address += listAdddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + " ";
                    }
                    address += listAdddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (address.equals("")) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");
            address += sdf.format(new Date());
        }

        Log.i("yes","all good");

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));

        Log.i("done","good");

        addresses.add(address);
        positions.add(latLng);

        MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.memorableplaces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {

            ArrayList<String> latitudes = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> longitudes = new ArrayList<>();

            for (LatLng coord : positions) {
                latitudes.add(Double.toString(coord.latitude));
                longitudes.add(Double.toString(coord.longitude));
            }

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(addresses)).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("lats", ObjectSerializer.serialize(latitudes)).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("lons", ObjectSerializer.serialize(longitudes)).apply();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ObjectSerializer class :

```
public class ObjectSerializer {


    public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj == null) return "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
            objStream.writeObject(obj);
            objStream.close();
            return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
            ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
            return objStream.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
            strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        }

        return strBuf.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
            c = str.charAt(i+1);
            bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ur MainActivity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(" com.example.memorableplaces",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

(notice the space before the package)

In ur MapsActivity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.memorableplaces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I saw u weren't use the same key of SharedPreferences to:

MainActivity

```
adresses, lats, lons
```

MapsActivity

```
places, lats, lons
```

U can also check if the preferences are correctly saved into the device file explorer at this location:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
```

Comment: Glad to help u, from what the problem comes from ? 

Don't forget to mark my answer as response if that helped u